# how to implement join using LINQ and EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to create a linq 2 sql in EF 4.0 query like following sql query.

```
SELECT * FROM Role
LEFT JOIN Queue 
ON Role.RoleId = Queue.RoleId 
WHERE QueueId = 361
```

So how could i do this in EF 4.0?

Comment: You mean Linq; not Linq to Sql.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: No, I'm pretty sure he meant LINQ to SQL. Or more accurately LINQ to Entities since he's mapping against EF. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx

Comment: @Mike LINQ to SQL is a completely different product from EF. It would be like saying he was talking about nHibernate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally this is done using navigation properties which are loaded when you get the entity, however you can also do this with the following:

```
from r in Roles
from q in Queues
where r.RoleId == q.RoleId
where q.QueueId == 361
select new { r.RoleId, q.QueueId /*other bits you want*/}
```

Comment: @Ali sure does, *from* indicates a datasource avaliable to the query in linq. This is similar to the concept of a JOIN inside SQL itself, and when the linq query gets translated to SQL this will turn into a SQL JOIN. I like multiple *from*'s in a query instead of a *join* statement as its much more readable

Answer (score 3):

try the following i hope it helps

i would recommend searching more about joins

```
var result=(from p in Roles
join pa in Queue on p.RoleId equals pa.RoleId into temproles
from addresses in temproles.DefaultIfEmpty() where temproles.queueId = 361
select new { p, pa} );
```